# Infinite loop in my Dijkstra algorithm implementation

Tags: c++, dijkstra

I am writing a program for an online judge programming contest. It is a simple dijkstra shortest path problem, but I am facing a really weird problem here.

After I read my input (commented as `#PROBLEM`), CPU use get's to 100% and the program doesn't do anything else: neither accept new input nor show any output. What is weird is that, if I comment out the `dijkstra()` function call right next to my `cin`s, the problem can't be reproduced again.

I am thinking about UB, but really can't find where the problem relies here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
#define INF 100001
#define vi vector<int>
#define ii pair<int, int>
#define vii vector<ii>

struct orderByCost {
 bool operator() (ii a, ii b) { return a.second > b.second; }
};

int dijkstra(const vector<vii> &adj, int start, int target) {
    vector<bool> visited(adj.size());
    priority_queue<ii, vector<ii>, orderByCost> pq;
    pq.push(ii(start, 0));
    vi costsTable(adj.size(), INF);
    while (!pq.empty()) {
        ii node = pq.top(); pq.pop();
        if (visited[node.first]) {
            continue;
        }
        visited[start] = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < adj[node.first].size(); i++)
        {
            ii neighbor = adj[node.first][i];
            if (!visited[neighbor.first]) {
                pq.push(neighbor);
            }
            if (costsTable[neighbor.first] == INF) {
                costsTable[neighbor.first] = neighbor.second;
            } else if (neighbor.second + costsTable[node.first] < costsTable[neighbor.first]) {
                costsTable[neighbor.first] += costsTable[node.first];
            }
        }
    }

    return costsTable[target];
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int n, e;
    while (true) {
        cin >> n >> e;
        if (n == e && e == 0) break;
        vector<vii> adj(n);
        for(int i = 0; i < e; i++)    {
            int a, b, w;
            cin >> a >> b >> w;
            a--; b--;
            adj[a].push_back(ii(b, w));
        }
        int cases;
        cin >> cases;
        for(int i = 0; i < cases; i++) {
            int a, b;
            cin >> a >> b; // #PROBLEM: this is the input that causes weird behavior
            a--; b--;
            int result = dijkstra(adj, a, b); // #PROBLEM: if I comment this line out, the following line WILL get printed. If not, CPU use get's 100% and just hangs
            cout << "This line isn't being printed\n";
            result > 0 ? cout << result << '\n' : cout << "Not possible\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Example input (**note:** lines starting with `#` are comments made by me for your understanding, **they are not** part of the input):

```
4 5 # 4 nodes with 5 edges
1 2 5 # edge from node 1 to node 2 with cost of 5
2 1 10
3 4 8
4 3 7
2 3 6
5 # test cases
1 2 # cost from path 1 to 2. Here is where the input hangs
1 3
1 4
4 3
4 1
3 3
```

My CPU use after reading input:
[image]

Comment: Sounds like you've got an infinite loop in the `dijkstra()` function, eh?

Comment: Replace cin input with an appropriate constant value. Reevaluate the situation and correct the title.

Comment: Dang. I guess we've all been there once... I completely missed that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to change

```
visited[start] = true;
```

into

```
visited[node.first] = true;
```

Otherwise only `start` node is ever marked as visited.

Comment: Ok, this is a little bit embarrassing. I've spend quite some time and didn't realize that. Thanks for pointing out. However, If I added a call to `std::cout` right in the beginning of the dijkstra function call, it wouldn't get printed in the buggy version. Could that possibly be a compiler intervention?

Comment: It may be because the line to be printed is still in the buffer and isn't flushed yet. You could use `std::cerr` and try again.